# Graph of a curve

Tags: graphing-functions, complex-geometry, plane-curves

Today in my test, there was a question which had contour **C**: $|z+\dfrac{1}{z}| = 2$.
 What does the curve represent? Is it a discrete set of points or really a curve?

Comment: I found that $z=\pm1$ satisfy the equation. But I have no idea what other points in the complex plane might satisfy it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fOreA.png

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: Write $z=x+iy$ and expand $\lvert z+z^{-1}\rvert^2=2^2$ to get a quadratic in $x^2$ and $y^2$, then apply the quadratic formula to solve for $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
|z+z^{-1}|=\frac{|z^2+1|}{|z|}=2 \iff |z^2+1|=2|z| \iff |z^2+1|^2=4|z|^2.
$$
Setting
$$
z=re^{i\theta},
$$
we get:
$$
4r^2=|r^2e^{i2\theta}+1|^2=(r^2e^{2i\theta}+1)(r^2e^{-2i\theta}+1)=r^4+2r^2\cos2\theta+1,
$$
i.e.
$$
0=r^4-2(2-\cos2\theta)r^2+1=r^4-2(1+2\sin^2\theta)r^2+1.
$$
It follows that
$$
r^2=1+2\sin^2\theta\pm\sqrt{(1+2\sin^2\theta)^2-1}.
$$
Hence $C$ is the union of the two curves
$$
C_+: \ r^2=1+2\sin^2\theta+\sqrt{(1+2\sin^2\theta)^2-1},\ \theta \in [0,2\pi]
$$
and
$$
C_-: \ r^2=1+2\sin^2\theta-\sqrt{(1+2\sin^2\theta)^2-1},\ \theta \in [0,2\pi].
$$
It's clear that $C_\pm$ is not a circle!

Answer (score 0):

From this diagram,

[image]

we can apply the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to get 
$$
4 = r^2 + 1/r^2 + 2\cos 2\theta
$$

which is a simple enough equation but I do not have enough experience in polar coordinates to recognize curve shapes. Solving that equation seems to get dirty rather quickly.